# Populate form after mySQL query with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to do this thing:

I have a html input textbox, some php code that makes a query on my database and return a JSON element, and in the end some javascript that I cannot figure to work the right way.

I simply want to do a live search while user is typing, than select one of the record found from the live search and populate a form with data of this record.

Probably there is a very simple solution, but I'm a newbie.

This is my html and Javascript code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>InChiaro Ticket Admin</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald" />
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint" />
    <link href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style-default.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_color" />
    <link href="../assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/bootstrap-fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="wrapper-principale">
            <div class="input-append search-input-area">
                <input type="text" class="search-filter" id="searchcodiceCliente" name="codiceCliente" placeholder="Cerca un cliente..." /> <!-- text AREA CODICE CLIENTE-->
                <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i> </button>
            </div>
            <div id="result" style="display:none">
                <table id="tablesearch"></table>
            </div>

            <form>
                <input type="text" id="CodiceCliente" />
                <input type="text" id="denominazione" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // We add the event on the class, which both inputs have
            $(".search-filter").keyup(function () {
                // Now we get the values from both inputs, using their ID's
                var codiceCliente = $("#searchcodiceCliente").val();
                //var fname = $("#searchfname").val();

                // Add both to the dataString (and URI encode the strings)

                var requestCodCliente = "get_codiceCliente_json"
                var json;
                // Check that at least one has any content
                if (codiceCliente != '')


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax_requests.php",
                        data: {
                            request: requestCodCliente,
                            searchCliente: codiceCliente
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            var x = document.getElementById("result");
                            x.style.display = "inline";
                            document.getElementById("tablesearch").innerHTML = '';
                            var th = "<tr><th></th><th>Codice Cliente</th><th>Denominazione</th><th>Indirizzo</th><th>Città</th><th>CAP</th><th>Numero Telefono</th></tr>";
                            document.getElementById("tablesearch").innerHTML += th;
                            function populateForm() {
                                document.getElementById("CodiceCliente").value = result[index].codiceCliente;
                            }
                            for (var index = 0; index < result.length; ++index) {

                                var t = "";

                                var tr = "<tr>";
                                tr += "<td><button id='select' class='btn'type='button' onclick='populateForm()'><i class='icon-search'></i></button></td>";
                                tr += "<td>"+result[index].codiceCliente+"</td>";
                                tr += "<td>"+result[index].denominazioneCliente+"</td>";
                                tr += "<td>"+result[index].indirizzo+"</td>";
                                tr += "<td>"+result[index].citta+"</td>";
                                tr += "<td>"+result[index].CAP+"</td>";
                                tr += "<td>"+result[index].numeroTelefono+"</td>";
                                tr += "</tr>";
                                t += tr;

                                document.getElementById("tablesearch").innerHTML += t;

                                }
                        }
                    });

            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is some sample output that I hope explains what I mean:

```
Codice cliente denominazione 
c00106         Paolo re
c00116         viglino arturo 
c00126         sellaro giuseppe
c00146         accusani fabio 
c00161         franconi srl
```

Thank You

Comment: So, what happens when you run this code? Btw, you're defining the function `populateForm()` inside the success callback, but you're not actually calling it anywhere. Why are you defining that function at all, instead of just calling the code inside directly?

Answer (score 1):

The aspect you are struggling with most is the attachment of `populateForm` as a click handler. As it stands, `onclick='populateForm()` won't work because `populateForm` would need to be a global member, and it's good practice not to pollute the global namespace.

To overcome this, click handling can be delegated to ancestor element of the buttons'; the `<table>` element is the most obvious choice. Fortunately, jQuery has a very convenient syntax for event delegation.

In addition, there is an issue you are probably not aware of; namely that multiple quick-fire AJAX requests will not necessarily respond in the expected order. On the assumption that order matters, a simple mechanism is available to ensure that table entries *are* in the expected order. All you need to do is :

- when each AJAX request is made, synchronously append a `<tbody>` element.
- keep a reference to each appended `<tbody>` element (in a closure).
- when each AJAX responses is received, append rows to the appropriate `<tbody>` element.

Your code should be something like this :

```
$(function () {
    // Delegate handling of button.btn clicks to the containing table element. 
    // This avoids having to attach the same click handler repeatedly to buttons in dynamically generated lines.
    $("#tablesearch").on('click', 'button.btn', function() {
        $("#CodiceCliente").val($(this).closest('td').next('td').text());
    });

    $(".search-filter").keyup(function() {
        var codiceCliente = $(this).val();
        if (codiceCliente != '') {
            var $tbody = $('<tbody/>').appendTo("#tablesearch"); // Synchronously append a <tbody> to receive two asynchrously generated <tr>s (see below).
            $.ajax({
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': 'ajax_requests.php',
                'data': {
                    'request': 'get_codiceCliente_json',
                    'searchCliente': codiceCliente
                },
            }).then(function (result) {
                $("#result").css('display', "inline");
                $("<tr><th></th><th>Codice Cliente</th><th>Denominazione</th><th>Indirizzo</th><th>Città</th><th>CAP</th><th>Numero Telefono</th></tr>").appendTo($tbody); // append to the correct <tbody> for this response
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
                    $("<tr><td><button class='btn'><i class='icon-search'></i></button></td><td>" + 
                    result[i].codiceCliente + "</td><td>" + 
                    result[i].denominazioneCliente + "</td><td>" + 
                    result[i].indirizzo + "</td><td>" + 
                    result[i].citta + "</td><td>" + 
                    result[i].CAP + "</td><td>" + 
                    result[i].numeroTelefono + "</td></tr>").appendTo($tbody); // append to the correct <tbody> for this response
                }
            }, function() {
                $tbody.remove(); // ajax failed so no point keeping the <tbody> element (unless you want to display an error message in the table)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help!

I edited my code to be like your, it returns me this error whenever I click on a button: Uncaught ReferenceError: populateForm is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: That error will not occur if the button HTML does not include `onclick="populateForm()"`. Make sure you are using my code in its entirety.

Comment: Also, I can't guarantee that the code is bug-free as I have tested it only for syntax errors. Be prepared to do some debugging.